# I need to move two shapes on their Y axis, how do I do so?

Tags: java, awt

Problem in my assignment calls for an arrow that moves up 50 pixels from its original state. It calls for a "moveUp" method, I need to use the `setYInt()` and `getYInt()` methods in order to do this.

This is my current code:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Arrow {
   private Canvas canvas;
   private Triangle head = new Triangle(120, 500, 50, 50, true);
   private Rectangle shaft = new Rectangle(140, 550, 10, 100);

   public Arrow(Canvas _canvas) {
      canvas = _canvas;
      Triangle head = new Triangle(120, 500, 50, 50, true);
      Rectangle shaft = new Rectangle(140, 550, 10, 100);
   }

   public void draw() {
      canvas.draw(head);
      canvas.draw(shaft);
   }

   public void erase() {
      canvas.erase(head);
      canvas.erase(shaft);
   }

   public void moveUp() {
      head.getYInt();
      shaft.getYInt();
      head.setYInt(head.getYInt - 50);
   }
}
```

Errors I'm getting with this code:

```
Arrow.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
      head.setYInt(head.getYInt - 50);
                       ^
  symbol:   variable getYInt
  location: variable head of type Triangle
1 error
```

I don't understand how I'm supposed to get the Y integer and set it to a different one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `head.getYInt()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
head.setYInt(head.getYInt - 50);
```

You are using `head.getYInt` which is no a function. Try `.getYInt()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
head.setYInt(head.getYInt - 50);
```

It seems you intend to invoke a method `setYInt()` on the head object. And most likely, you meant to use `head.getYInt()` to **first** retrieve the current Y value.

So: either use getter/setter methods all over the place, or (not recommended), simply access the corresponding fields.

Beyond that:

```
private Triangle head = new Triangle(120, 500, 50, 50, true);
```

...

```
public Arrow(Canvas _canvas) {
  Triangle head = new Triangle(120, 500, 50, 50, true);
```

Doesn't make much sense: you initialized `head` already, so doing it again isn't meaningful. Worse: you are actually **not** initializing your field head within the constructor, you create a local variable, initialize that, and then forget about it.